# Displaying a DialogFragment is confusing me

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am going over the [official Android tutorial for DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). The part that slightly confuses me is:

```
void showDialog() {
    mStackLevel++;

    // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
    // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
    // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Create and show the dialog.
    DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mStackLevel);
    newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
}
```

So my confusion arises from the fact that they are using `findFragmentByTag("dialog")`. Nowhere is a layout XML declared that has a tag named `dialog` in it. In case of normal Fragmants, there are `<fragment ../>` tags in the layout so I can retrieve fragments with Id or tagname. Here, there isn't any.

So, what gives ? How does this work ?
Also, what if I have multiple `DialogFragments` ? `findFragmentByTag("dialog");` will return what??

:)

Comment: *Also, how do I make this work with a support DialogFragment?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments can be attached to an Activity in two ways: statically by declaring it in the layout xml using the `<fragment>` tag; or programmatically using `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction`. In the case of DialogFragments, you will always be using the latter.

When you attach a fragment to the Activity, such as by using [`DialogFragment.show()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentTransaction,%20java.lang.String%29), you can give it a tag. The `FragmentManager` can then later find this fragment by its tag. In this case, the code is checking if the `FragmentManager` already has a fragment with this tag (which I believe would be the case if the dialog was already showing when `showDialog()` was called). If so, it removes the fragment (dismissing the dialog) before showing a new instance of it.

Comment: So, this 'tag' is more like a key-value pair rather than an XML tag

Comment: You could think of it that way.